# Populate datagridview without locking form

Tags: multithreading, powershell

Using powershell and windows forms, I have an application with a datagridview that I'm trying to populate. For the sake of the example, let's say my code is the following:

```
    $button1_Click={
    For ($i = 0; $i -lt 100000; $i++)
    {
        $datagridview1.Rows.Add($i.ToString())
    }
```

During the time it takes for the for instruction to run (around 13 seconds on this particular example on my computer), the form will obviously be locked.

I am basically trying to find a way of doing this so that the datagridview keeps updating without locking the form. I don't care if it even takes longer to run, so long as the form is usable.

Here's what I've tried:

- Start-Job, but since Start-Job can't interact directly with my datagridview, I'd need to wait for the job to complete so that I can retrieve the result and then add it to the datagridview. To do so would involve a Wait-Job which would lock the form whilst the Wait-Job is running.
- Register-ObjectEvent, but this doesn't work as expected when using windows forms.
- Looked at using a backgroundworker but realized it's not possible in Powershell

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use `[Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()`.  You don't need to call it every time through the loop. Say every 5000 iterations or you could base it on time.  Perhaps after 250 millisecs have elapsed since the last call to DoEvents:

```
$button1_Click = {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 100000; $i++) {
        $datagridview1.Rows.Add($i.ToString())
        if ($i % 5000 -eq 0) { [Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that would definitely work in the example I gave and it's definitely a step in the right direction. However (as you probably assumed) I'm not just adding a number to my datagridview. I'm doing some AD lookups and depending on the result (does object exist, is it member of certain group, can I add it to the group, etc) that's what I add to the datagridview. In my particular case it's not the form refresh that's locking the form but all of the other code being run (AD lookups). So in my case calling DoEvents() will not work too well I think. Sorry for not being so clear before.